# Does UPDATE increment @@trancount by 1?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I understand that `BEGIN TRAN` increments `@@trancount` by 1 and `COMMIT TRAN` decrements `@@trancount` by 1, but what about the `UPDATE` statement? What effect does it have, especially in implicit transactions?

I looked up info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trancount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
but the `UPDATE` statement was never mentioned.

```
BEGIN TRY

    UPDATE cad
    SET [AccountExpirationDate] = DATEADD(MONTH, -13, [AccountExpirationDate])
    FROM [dbo].[CardActivationDetail] cad
    WHERE ci.[CardOrderId] = @CardOrderId;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@trancount > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```

In the example I posted this is an implicit transaction with a begin/try catch applied. How is `@@Trancount` working in this scenario? Does the Update statement increment it by 1 and the auto-commit decrement it by 1, leaving `@@trancount = 0`?

Comment: No, an update is still inside the same transaction.

Comment: Why not simply test this? Hint...no an update statement does NOT increment trancount. And even if did the behavior or incrementing it and then decrementing it what difference would it be?

Comment: @SeanLange it does increment trancount as shown in the answer

Answer (score 2):

> What effect does a [DML statement] have [on @@trancount], especially in implicit transactions?

With implicit_transactions on, if @@trancount = 0 then it increments @@trancount twice, runs and decrements it by one, runs any after triggers, leaving it at 1.

With implicit_transactions off, if @@trancount = 0 it increments @@trancount twice, runs and decrements it by one, runs any AFTER triggers, and decrements it again, committing.

In either case if @@trancount > 0 then it increments @@trancount by one, runs,  decrements it by one, runs any AFTER triggers.

You can see this behavior in deadlock graphs, and by using @@trancount in your DML.

eg:

```
use tempdb
drop table if exists t
set nocount on
go
create table t(id int identity, a int)

go
create trigger tt on t after insert
as
begin
  select @@trancount trancount_in_trigger
end
go
set implicit_transactions off
go
if @@trancount > 0 rollback
go
print '---autocommit----'
select @@trancount trancount_before
insert into t(a) values (@@trancount)
select a trancount_during from t where id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
select @@trancount trancount_after

go

begin transaction
print '---explicit transaction----'
select @@trancount trancount_before
insert into t(a) values (@@trancount)
select a trancount_during from t where id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
select @@trancount trancount_after

commit

go

begin transaction
begin transaction
print '---explicit nested transaction----'
select @@trancount trancount_before
insert into t(a) values (@@trancount)
select a trancount_during from t where id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
select @@trancount trancount_after

commit
commit

go 

set implicit_transactions on

go
print '---implicit transaction----'
select @@trancount trancount_before
insert into t(a) values (@@trancount)
select a trancount_during from t where id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
select @@trancount trancount_after

commit
```

outputs

```
---autocommit----
trancount_before
----------------
0

trancount_in_trigger
--------------------
1

trancount_during
----------------
2

trancount_after
---------------
0

---explicit transaction----
trancount_before
----------------
1

trancount_in_trigger
--------------------
1

trancount_during
----------------
2

trancount_after
---------------
1

---explicit nested transaction----
trancount_before
----------------
2

trancount_in_trigger
--------------------
2

trancount_during
----------------
3

trancount_after
---------------
2

---implicit transaction----
trancount_before
----------------
0

trancount_in_trigger
--------------------
1

trancount_during
----------------
2

trancount_after
---------------
1
```